# Need to find registry entry where the Dragon Profile Path is stored

Tags: windows, powershell, software-distribution, naturallyspeaking, nuance

Have a task to update Dragon Profile Path. Dragon v11

Kind of an overview here of the application.
http://nuance.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6887/kw/dragon%20profile%20path

I found the ini file that stores the dragon profile path however when i update it in the ini file, it doesn't replicate over to the application itself and still has the old path.

Was wondering if anyone has run into something similar and may have any suggestions.

btw: dragon profile path can be changed from the application but i have a task to update about 150 systems that on and don't want to go manually on each system and do it :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Dragon's support website lists the following keys in their lengthy [uninstall doc](http://nuance.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2522/%7E/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-dragon-naturallyspeaking%3F):

```
HKCU:\Software\Dragon
HKCU:\Software\Dragon Systems
HKCU:\Software\ScanSoft\NaturallySpeaking x.x
HKLM:\Software\Dragon
HKLM:\Software\Dragon Systems
HKLM:\Software\Elan Informatique
HKLM:\Software\L&H\NaturallySpeaking
HKLM:\Software\ScanSoft\NaturallySpeaking x.x
Where "x.x" is any version number.
```

Be aware `HKCU:` is only valid for the logged-in user.

In general, I recommend using ProcessMonitor to see which file or registry key gets changed right as you make the change (if you can't find it any reasonable way.)

Comment: eh none of those exist in the registry.

Comment: @HishamRafi Do you actually have dragon installed locally, or are you using some portable version?

Comment: installed locally

Comment: Found the solution:https://nuancecommunity.force.com/NuanceHealthcareSupport/s/article/Distribute-Roaming-Network-Directory-change-using-Roamingini14038